# Is using only 3 timestamps for a bitemporal SQL database possible?

Tags: sql, database, bi-temporal

When implementing a bitemporal database in SQL, it is usually recommended to use the following timestamps:

- ValidStart
- ValidEnd
- TransactionStart
- TransactionEnd

I have used this approach  a few times before, but I  have always wondered why having only 3 timestamps, leaving TransactionEnd out, isn't just as correct an implementation. Here a transaction time range spans from TransactionStart to the next TransactionStart.

Are there any strong arguments for not only using 3 timestamps, which will limit the size of the database?

Comment: simplicity: both data are in the same row, much easier to do your operations

Comment: In the case of only one  row, transactionEnd  is not realy defined maybe`inf` as default value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment it's for simplicity, since it's somewhat harder to make certain queries without it.

Consider the following example. `John` is born in some location,  `Location1`, on January first 1990, but is first registered to be born on the fifth.

The database table, `Persons`, now looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
|   Name   | Location     | valid_from | valid_to | trans_from | trans_to |
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| John     | Location1    | 01-01-1990 |99-99-9999| 05/01/1990 |99-99-9999|
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

At this point, removing the `trans_to` column wouldn't cause too much trouble, but suppose the following:

After some years, say 20, `John` relocates to `Location2`, and inform the officials 20 days later.
This will make the `Persons` table look like this

```
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
|   Name   | Location     | valid_from | valid_to | trans_from | trans_to |
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| John     | Location1    | 01-01-1990 |99-99-9999| 05/01/1990 |20-01-2010|
| John     | Location1    | 01-01-1990 |01-01-2010| 20/01/2010 |99-99-9999|
| John     | Location2    | 01-01-2010 |99-99-9999| 20/01/2010 |99-99-9999|
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Suppose someone wanted to find out "Where does the system think John is living now" (transaction time), regardless of where he *actually* lives. This can (roughly) be queried in SQL in the following way

```
Select  Location
From    Persons
Where   Name = John AND trans_from > NOW AND trans_to < NOW
```

Suppose the transaction end time was removed

```
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+
|   Name   | Location     | valid_from | valid_to | trans_from |
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+
| John     | Location1    | 01-01-1990 |99-99-9999| 05/01/1990 |
| John     | Location1    | 01-01-1990 |01-01-2010| 20/01/2010 |
| John     | Location2    | 01-01-2010 |99-99-9999| 20/01/2010 |
+----------+--------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

The query above is of course no longer valid, but making logic for the same query in the last table would be somewhat difficult. Since the `trans_to` is missing it will have to be derived from the other rows in the table. For instance the implicit `trans_to` time for the first row (since its the oldest entry) is the `trans_from` from the second row, which is the newer of the two.

The transaction end time is thus either `9999-99-99`, if the row is the newest, *or* it's the `trans_from` from the row immediately succeeding it.

This means that the data concerning a specific row, is not entirely kept in that row, and the rows form a dependency on each other, which is (of course) unwanted. Furthermore it can be quite difficult to determine which exact row is the immediate successor of a row, which can make the queries even more complex

Answer (score 1):

An example of using only one timestamp instead of two in an 1D temporal database:

I have a shop and I want to record when an user X was in my shop.

If I use a model with start-time and end-time, this info can be recorded as

```
X,1,2
X,3,4
```

so user X was in my shop between 1 and 2 and between 3 and 4. This is clear, simple and concise.

If I model my data with only start-time as a timestamp, I will have:

```
X,1
X,2
X,3
X,4
```

but how I can interpret this data?
X from (1,2) and X from (3,4)? or X from (2,3) and X from (1,4)? 
or X from (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)?  X from (4,inf) is valid?

To understand this data I need to add additional constraints/logic/information to my data or code:
maybe the intervals are non-overlaping, maybe I add an id per object, etc. 
All this solutions are not working in all cases, can be difficult to be maintained and other issues.

For e.g.: if I add  an id(a,b in this case) to every item, it will result :

```
X,a,1
X,a,2
X,b,3
X,b,4
```

instead to store my data in 2 rows,3 columns my data will be stored in 4 rows, 3 columns.
Not only I don't have any benefits using this model but this model can be reduced to:

```
X,a, 1,2 
X,b, 3,4
```

further reduced to

```
X, 1,2
X, 3,4
```